# How to ORDER BY count of rows with specific column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

I have a SQL select statement as follows:

```
select * from editortemp order by case 
when CategoryID = 10 then 0 
else CategoryID end,
Ranking
```

I would like to change the ordering of the result, so that in addition to putting all rows with CategoryID = 10 at the top, the REST of the rows will be ordered according to the count of the rows with each CategoryID, in descending order.

When I try doing

```
select * from editortemp order by case 
when CategoryID = 10 then 0 
else count(CategoryID) end,
Ranking
```

I get the error: Column 'editortemp.EditorTempID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

After researching this error online, it looks like this means there's a problem with the logic of the select statement.

How do I create a logical select statement which will order the rows as I described above?

EDIT: When I try to run the following statement:

```
 select * from editortemp order by case 
    when CategoryID = 10 then 0 
    else (select count(CategoryID) from editortemp) end,
    Ranking
```

I don't get the error mentioned above, but the ordering does not come out right. It puts all category=10 rows at the top, but then starts ordering according to the ranking, not according to the count of the categoryid... Any ideas what needs to be changed to get the results I want?

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Probably not relevant here, but you should always add a tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Comment: The reason the last query isn't working is because you're counting all rows in `EditorTemp` - you don't have a correlation clause.  So each row gets the same value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really show a sample structure of your tables, some sample data and sample of what you are expecting in your original post.

From the way it looks, your editortemp table has multiple records and may have more data elements obviously not presented here.  I would first get a pre-aggregate of counts, then join back to include as part of your ordering.  Something like

```
select 
      et.* 
   from 
      editortemp
         JOIN ( select categoryID, count(*) as CatCount
                   from editortmp
                   group by categoryID ) preAgg
            on et.categoryID = preAgg.categoryID
   order by 
      case when CategoryID = 10 then 1 else 2 end,
      preAgg.CatCount desc,
      ranking
```

The case/when will force a preliminary sort of categoryID = 10 first, then anything else second.  The secondary part of the order by is the count from the pre-aggregate table joined to.   So, even if Category 10 has a count of 3 entries and Category 2 has 100, Category 10 still stays at the first spot... only then do the rest get sorted in descending order by count.

Per feedback...

I Don't know what the ranking is, but the ranking should only be an impact if there are multiple entries for a given category count.

```
What if categories 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 all have a count of 73 entries... and 
cat 1 has a ranks of 6, 12, 15...
cat 2 has ranks of 3, 20, 40...
cat 3 has ranks of 9, 10, 18... 
they will be intermingled.
```

If you want all of same category grouped, then that would be added before ranking something like

```
   order by 
      case when CategoryID = 10 then 1 else 2 end,
      preAgg.CatCount desc,
      CategoryID,
      ranking
```

This way, inf the scenario of multiple categories having the count of 73, then the above order by will have all of category 1 by its ranking, then category 2 by its ranking, etc.

Comment: I'd probably move the `CASE` into the subquery, which should make things a little cleaner.  Oh, you've also left off `ranking`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, added the ranking, but by putting the case in the subquery, then hoping it all comes out in that order with the outer-based editortemp can't guarantee proper case order, that is why I have it at the final query level.

Comment: @DRapp - thank you, this was a great help! I see that you have added the Ranking in the order by clause at the end. 
When I leave out Ranking the sort works properly, however when I add it in as you did, the original sort doesn't work any more... Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @user1463201, revised answer to clarify ranking issue you may be seeing.

Comment: I think you got it. This seems to work now, and what you write makes sense. I also checked, and it is true that in this particular case the table held more than one category with the same number of entries.

Comment: What I meant was a subquery like `SELECT categoryId, CASE WHEN categoryId = 10 THEN -1 ELSE COUNT(*) END AS catCount...`.  This would mean your top level `ORDER BY` just has to reference the `catCount` column (we could use `0` for the "count" for `categoryId = 10`, as the current statement only deals with existing rows, but just in case it gets changed to caring about 0-count rows...).

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   TEMP1.* 
from 
     (
      select CategoryID, 999999999 AS Ranking FROM editortemp WHERE CategoryID = 10
      UNION ALL
      Select CategoryID, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM editortemp AS t1 WHERE t1.CategoryID = t2.CategoryID) AS Ranking FROM editortemp AS t2 WHERE CategoryID <> 10
      ) TEMP1
ORDER BY
    TEMP1.Ranking DESC
```

Comment: Don't you need a correlation between the main query and the sub-query? (To make sure a correct count?)

Comment: @user1463201 i have changed query check now

Comment: You should not depend on a `union all` query returning the rpws from the first query first followed by the rows from the second.  This is not guaranteed.

Comment: The op wants the other set of row (`categoryId <> 10`) ordered by the count of rows for that category, so this won't work.

Comment: ....you'd be better of using something that _can't_ occur for a counted row (although `999999999` is unlikely, I'll admit).  Like `0`, or `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want as:

```
order by (case when CategoryID = 10 then 0 else 1 end),
         (case when CategoryID <> 10
               then (select count(*) from editortemp et2 where et2.CategoryID = editortemp.CategoryId)
          end),
         Ranking
```

The first clause puts `CategoryId` 10 at the top.  The second sorts the rest by the number of category ids.  The third uses `Ranking` as the final sort column.

Comment: ...Isn't this likely to run the subquery for every row being ordered?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . Yes, but it was the suggestion of the OP to do it this way.  In addition, with an index on `editortemp(CategoryId)`, the performance would probably be okay.